# Powershell parse duration string into seconds

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a string like this: "00:02:37.6940000". Is there an easy way to convert/parse that into seconds?  Do I have to regex it into pieces and do it that way?

I don't care about the milliseconds.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Parse is the default method of the [TimeSpan] type, so:

```
([timespan]"00:02:37.6940000").TotalSeconds
```

should work, too.

With error trapping:

```
$input_ts = "00:02:37.6940000" 

if ($input_ts -as [TimeSpan])
  {$time = ([TimeSpan]$input_ts).TotalSeconds}

else {Write-Warning "Input value $input_ts not valid for timespan"}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Worked perfectly.

Comment: Is there a way to catch a bad one and not have it blow up?  Like if the string was "abc123" or null or something.

Comment: Updated posted script with an option for error trapping.  You could also use try/catch, but I think that might be overkill.

Comment: Another alternative is to use `[TimeSpan]::TryParse()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the format of of timespan object you can use

```
[Timespan]::Parse("00:02:37.6940000")
```